# Finding position of largest int in list

Tags: python

```
if key == "m":
    position = position.index(max(list))
```

Hi can someone see where im going wrong i want the `list[position]` to take the value of the largest integer position in the list

Comment: `position = list.index(max(list))`

Comment: What you're doing is not clear. If you want *to take the value of the largest integer*, why are you applying `index()`? Moreover, why apply it to `position`? What is `position` in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

The "index" method belongs to your list, so you should do something like:

```
position = list.index(max(list))
```

However you should avoid to use reserved build-in symbols like `list`, just use some other name.

Answer (score -2):

The largest element of list can be fetched using `max(a)` where a is the list.
So what you can do is `a.insert(<index>,max(a))`. So you can set position of your max element using the same.